# How to change widget visibility from outside of OnCreate method? Java Android Studio

Tags: java, android, static

I have a seekbar that I want to disappear when I press a button, and reappear after a countdown. I have used `seekBarTimeToPlay.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);` in the `onFinish()` method after the countdown.

However, I get the error "cannot resolve symbol 'view'." And also "cannot resolve symbol 'seekBarTimeToPlay'." but seem to resolve this by adding another `SeekBar seekBarTimeToPlay = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarTimeToPlay);` inside the method.

```
    //change timeToPlay seekBar
    SeekBar seekBarTimeToPlay = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarTimeToPlay);
    //set progress/thumb pos to right place
    seekBarTimeToPlay.setProgress(timeToPlay);

    seekBarTimeToPlay.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            timeToPlay = progress;
            updateTimeToPlay(timeToPlay, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
           updateTimeToPlay(timeToPlay, true);
        }
    });

    //start playing, countdown
    final Button buttonMain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMain);
    buttonMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //countdown, updating time to tidy text view, progress bar or clock animation

            SeekBar seekBarTimeToPlay = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarTimeToPlay);

            if (phase == "none") { //parent presses button, child starts playing
                phase = "playing";
                buttonMainText = "Pack Away Now";
                //hide seekBar, doesn't change layout
                seekBarTimeToPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                startCountDown(timeToPlay);

            } else if (phase == "playing") {//parent presses button to pack away before time ended
                phase = "tidying";
                buttonMainText = "Confirm tidied up";
                countDownTimer.cancel(); //maybe error if countdown isn't running, if statement might solve
                updateTimeToPlay(timeToTidy, false);
                startCountDown(timeToTidy); //new 10 minute countdown to wait for conformation that toys are away
                //waiting to receive conformation, if received cancel countdown n that

            } else if (phase == "tidying") { //parent presses button confirming packed away
                countDownTimer.cancel(); //maybe error if countdown isn't running, if statement might solve
                phaseWasTidying();
            }

            buttonMain.setText(buttonMainText); //change text to whatever stage

            //returns here after button pressed
            seekBarTimeToPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //make visible again
        }
    });
}
```

How do I change visibility from another method? I also cannot use `static` which I don't understand.

Comment: You are setting visibility to `View.INVISIBLE` and few lines below to `View.VISIBLE` maybe that is the reason why you don't see any effect/result.

Comment: shouldn't that only be executed once it has returned from countdown function? or does countdown start in a new thread or something? thanks

Comment: you were right and it works, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View should start from uppercase beacue it's class name:

```
seekBarTimeToPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

or

```
seekBarTimeToPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

---

And remember about import:

`import android.view.View;`

Comment: that seemed to fix it not being recognised but it doesn't change visibility?